# System keeps rebooting when accessing memory after removing identity memory mapping

Tags: c++, assembly, kernel, x86-64, osdev

I'm writing a custom OS kernel for x86-64. It uses a UEFI boot loader to load the kernel to a random free location provided by the UEFI. In the kernel, it first relocates to a high address direct mapping region. After I successfully set the `RIP` `RSP` and `RBP`, I decided to remove the identity mapped virtual pages. But it triggers the reboot as soon as I access the memory right after the removal of the pages.

P.S. The kernel is using rip-relative for both function calls and variable accesses, so the relocation of the kernel itself shouldn't be a problem.

I thought it might be the problem of the GDT. When the reboot occurred, I was still using the UEFI-provided GDT, and its addresses was based on the identity mapped address. But after I created my own GDT and confirmed it was ok to access the memory with it, the problem was still there.

I also disabled the interrupt by using `asm volatile("cli":::"memory");` in case it was caused by the IDT.

Comment: I don't see any code let alone a [mcve]. Also, learn to use a debugger. The cpu is never wrong, so you must have done the paging wrong but we can't tell.

Comment: @Jester I really want to use the debugger, but how can I debug a program which is loaded at different memory address each time I boot up the system?

Comment: Not sure what that has to do with anything. Use the debugger to catch the fault then examine page tables and GDT and whatnot. In any case, you can fix the address for some initial tests instead of randomizing. Easiest if you can reproduce the error in a VM.

Comment: You removed the identity mapping and replaced it with what? You cannot disable paging in long mode.

Comment: Bochs's built-in debugger is reportedly good, and should have good support for showing you exceptions.  It can dump its idea of your page tables and the GDT, to let you check that they're what you expected.  (I assume it supports UEFI booting but haven't checked.)

Comment: It's not clear whether you have called ExitBootServices or not, but you certainly cannot remove any of the existing mappings until after you have done that.

Comment: If you make any EFI call, to allocate or free memory, for example, or anything else, it reenables interrupts.

Comment: @MargaretBloom I mapped the physical memory with direct mapping at `0xFFFF880000000000`(temporarily)

Comment: @prl I called `ExitBootServices` in my UEFI OS loader, and currently I'm not using a single UEFI runtime service